# Manually register a user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to manually register a user (with artisan?) rather than via the auth registration page?

I only need a handful of user accounts and wondered if there's a way to create these without having to set up the registration controllers and views.

Comment: Through tinker ... php artisan tinker

Answer (score 228, accepted):

I think you want to do this once-off, so there is no need for something fancy like creating an Artisan command etc. I would suggest to simply use `php artisan tinker` (great tool!) and add the following commands per user:

```
$user = new App\Models\User();
$user->password = Hash::make('the-password-of-choice');
$user->email = 'the-email@example.com';
$user->name = 'My Name';
$user->save();
```

Comment: No, this is not an artisan command. This is ***using*** an artisan command.

Comment: Yea, this is pretty zen. Thanks. @maiorano84 it's this package in L5 (laravel/framework/composer.json) https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh

Comment: If your project is requiring names as well, use the line `$user->name = 'John Doe';` before the `save()` line.

Comment: You may also need to set the username `$user->username = 'my username';`  before `$user->save()`

Comment: For some reason I can't login using data inserted via Tinker... Guard won't let me in, passwords are not matched. Any ideas?

Comment: @Wirone make sure to use the email address, not the username, to login. Also, you need to use Hash::make() to generate the password, if you just stored an unhashed password it wont work

Comment: @WilliamRandokun I am sure that I did everything exactly as described above (including `Hash::make()`) and was using email for login and it did not work. Did it more than once. Now I tested it again and it worked, magic!

Comment: Laravel 8: `$user = new App\Models\User();`

Comment: This did not work for me using docker image sail-8.0/app @Diverti's answer was the solution for me.

Answer (score 69):

This is an old post, but if anyone wants to do it with command line, in Laravel 5.*, this is an easy way:

```
php artisan tinker
```

then type (replace with your data):

```
DB::table('users')->insert(['name'=>'MyUsername','email'=>'thisis@myemail.com','password'=>Hash::make('123456')])
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the best option is to create a seeder, so you can always reuse it.

For example, this is my `UserTableSeeder`:

```
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run() {

    if(env('APP_ENV') != 'production')
    {
        $password = Hash::make('secret');

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
        {
            $users[] = [
                'email' => 'user'. $i .'@myapp.com',
                'password' => $password
            ];
        }

        User::insert($users);
    }
}
```

After you create this seeder, you must run `composer dumpautoload`, and then in your `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` add the following:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
     }
}
```

Now you can finally use `php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder` every time you need to insert users in the table.

Comment: my laravel version is 5.4 and there is no any need of 'composer dumpautoload' and even not need to call UserTableSeeder in DatabaseSeeder. Just used the command "php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder" after creating the class "UserTableSeeder" as yours..

Comment: This was needed with Laravel 5.2 in 2016.

Comment: Just a note that if you are using a seeder like this (with intention of reuse), you are most going to be storing your password in plaintext in a git repo with this solution. Proceed with caution, & abstract your password out to an environmental variable.

Comment: This is the best approach. Check out this link for an up-to-date implementation example:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/seeding#writing-seeders

Answer (score 6):

You can also create a new console command which can be called from the command line. This is especially useful if you want to create new users on demand.

This example makes use of [laravel fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify) but you can also use your own user registration logic.

First create a new [console command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan):

```
php artisan make:command CreateUserCommand
```

Then add the implementation:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;

class CreateUserCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'user:create {--u|username= : Username of the newly created user.} {--e|email= : E-Mail of the newly created user.}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Manually creates a new laravel user.';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     * https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Enter username, if not present via command line option
        $name = $this->option('username');
        if ($name === null) {
            $name = $this->ask('Please enter your username.');
        }

        // Enter email, if not present via command line option
        $email = $this->option('email');
        if ($email === null) {
            $email = $this->ask('Please enter your E-Mail.');
        }

        // Always enter password from userinput for more security.
        $password = $this->secret('Please enter a new password.');
        $password_confirmation = $this->secret('Please confirm the password');

        // Prepare input for the fortify user creation action
        $input = [
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
            'password_confirmation' => $password_confirmation
        ];

        try {
            // Use fortify to create a new user.
            $new_user_action = new CreateNewUser();
            $user = $new_user_action->create($input);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->error($e->getMessage());
            return;
        }

        // Success message
        $this->info('User created successfully!');
        $this->info('New user id: ' . $user->id);
    }
}
```

You can execute the command via:

```
php artisan user:create -u myusername -e mail@example.com
```

I recommend to always ask for the password via the user input, not as parameter for [security reasons](https://www.netmeister.org/blog/passing-passwords.html).

Comment: and then easy to use with: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan; Artisan::call('Commandname');

Comment: I added fortify to a basic site of mine and needed a quick way to just add a single account since I don't have a register page. Didn't want to have a plain text password saved in files, so this did the trick

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily write a database [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding) and seed your users that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Model Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#model-factories)** to generate a couple of user account to work it. Writing a **seeder** will also get the job done.