# Laravel simple custom authorization without token or database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization

What would be for me simplest way to make custom authentication for this scenario

1. I have login form
2. upon submitting I am currently sending axios request to custom API (there is no token)
3. if user exists axios response will contain username, first name, last name and uuid
4. how to proceed now and auth that user to Laravel?

I want to use methods Auth::attempt(), Auth::user() and other Laravel's functionality to easy access session data, but not sure how to store it

edit note: I'm not using laravel's(or any other) database

Answer (score 0):

You can register your user (after axio response) to Laravel, then log this user.

From this page : [Manually register a user in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753951/manually-register-a-user-in-laravel), create the user :

```
$user = new App\User();
$user->password = Hash::make( str_random(12) );
$user->email = $responseAxiosEmail;
$user->username = $responseAxiosUsername;
// need to add this field in your DB to store uuid and test if user already exists
$user->uuid = $rseponseAxioUuid;
$user->save();
```

Then you case use Auth::login() :

```
Auth::login($user);
```

If your user already exists, you can find it by uuid and use :

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
```

More informations : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: forgot to mention but I'm not using a database, any workarounds? will edit above as well