# Laravel: Using only password auth for intranet app

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am trying to build password protection for my app that requires only a predefined password then would create a session that will last for 4 hours "work shift hours" before expiring.. it is intranet project that I just need to provide some level of protection..
So I will basically use DB to store the password and sessions.

All laravel docs require the laravel ui/auh to be implemented to work.. and I would like to build one of my own but I can't find where to start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the default Laravel authentication mechanism so you don't have to mess with session handling etc.

You can remove all the default authentication routes and views. (If you've already scaffolded your application with the auth routes, remove `Auth::routes()` from your routes file.)

Then add one user to the database, perhaps called "Intranet user". It doesn't matter what you set as password/email. You can create this user with `artisan tinker` ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35754495/4667355)).

Create a view with a form that only asks for the password and makes a POST request to a custom controller (for example `LoginController`). This controller simply checks if the password is correct, and logs in the user with: `Auth::login($user)`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
      return view("auth.login"); // Path to your login view (login form)
    }

    public function login($id)
    {
        $password = $request->input('password');

        if ($password === "your-predefined-password") {
          $user = User::findOrFail(1); // The ID of the only user in the system

          Auth::login($user); // Log the user in

          // Redirect somewhere
          return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }

        // If the password didn't match, redirect back the the login page
        return redirect('login')->with('error', 'Wrong password!');
    }
}
```

routes.php:

```php
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/user', 'LoginController@login');
```

To limit the session lifetime, open up `config/sessions.php` and adjust the lifetime to 240 minutes (= 4 hours):

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 240),
```

**Alternative solution:**

Instead of hardcoding the password in `LoginController`, create a password and email for the user. Then make a login attempt like this:

```php
$credentials = [
  'email' => 'intranet@intranet',
  'password' => $request->input('password')
];

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
  return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: That is interesting I will give it a try but can u tell if you can incorporate the vanilla auth system on a non-fresh laravel project.. cz i already got alot going on and all docs explain in regard to a fresh project..

Comment: I am worried if I do "php artisan ui vue --auth" or bootstrap itmay messup some of my already presennt code

Comment: You don't really need to run the command. You only need to create a login form that makes a POST request to the LoginController defined above. I've updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: I did use the "php artisan ui vue --auth" on the existing project and used ur method and it worked great! thank you!